# Java abstracting the use of instanceof for collecting classes from List

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following hierarchy of classes:

```
public class MainClass {

}

class A extends MainClass {

}

class B extends MainClass {

}

class C extends MainClass {

}
```

Now suppose I have a `List<MainClass> classes` which looks like:

```
 {A, MainClass, A, B, B, MainClass, C, A, C, B, A}
```

I want to be able to pick out sublists of objects by their class. For example, I would like to be able to extract only those classes in this list of class A (but not class MainClass). As such, using isAssignableFrom(A.class) will not work for me.

My current method looks like:

```
public <T extends MainClass> List<T> getClasses(List<MainClass> classes, Class classToCollect) {
    List<T> subclasses = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (MainClass clazz : classes) {
        if (clazz.getClass().isInstance(classToCollect)) {
            subclasses.add((T)clazz);
        }
    }

    return subclasses;
}
```

This still doesn't work and passes back an empty list. What gives here?

Comment: Why don't you just see if the class objects are equal?

Comment: This also works `clazz.getClass().getName().equals(A.class.getName())` and `clazz.getClass().equals(A.class)`

Comment: The parameter of type List<MainClass> should be named something like 'objects'.  It is not a list of class-es, but a list of objects.  Similarly, the for loop variable should be called something like object, as again, it will hold objects not classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition should look like this:

```
for (MainClass obj : classes) {
    if (classToCollect.isInstance(obj)) {
        subclasses.add((T)obj);
    }
}
```

The name `clazz` is misleading, because it is actually an object.

You can further improve type safety of your code by using `Class<T>` in the method header:

```
public <T extends MainClass> List<T> getClasses(List<MainClass> classes, Class<T> classToCollect) {
    ...
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/aHEAyO)

Note: This would not work if you pass `MainClass.class` as the second argument (Thanks, `JB Nizet`, for a great comment).

Comment: The usage of the term class instead of instance/object looks more like a misunderstanding on OP's side.

Comment: Oops, `clazz` was my fault. `class` was initially used, so I changed it before anyone complained about bad syntax. Should I change it?

Comment: I'd like to know what's the java 8 equivalent of this, since one would expect to do a simple `.OfType<MyClass>()` like you see in modern languages...

Comment: @HighCore `classes.stream().filter(A.class::isInstance)`

Comment: @HighCore or `classes.stream().filter(a -> a instanceof A)`

Comment: @HighCore: `classes.stream().filter(classToCollect::isInstance).toList()`.

Comment: Not sure if it's a problem for the OP, but if he also hopes to get the MainClass instances that are not A, B nor C instances by passing MainClass.class, that won't work. In that case, he'll have to check that the classes are equal.

Comment: @LouisWasserman still looks really ugly with that `.stream()` boilerplate and all the horrid lower casing.

Comment: That should probably be `public <T> List<T> getClasses(List<? super T> list, Class<T> clazz)` to be as generic as possible.

Comment: Using getClass().getName().equals and getClass().equals did the trick for me. For some reason, I had the same solution as this answer, but on my end, I was getting an empty count even when I debugged and could visibly see the class I wanted in the list. Thanks for the answers and comments!

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 you could express it this way:

```
public <T> List<T> getClasses(List<? super T> instances, Class<T> classToCollect) {
    return instances.stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getClass() == classToCollect)
                    .map(c -> (T) c)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```